# protected integers in static classes

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static, primitive

Let's say I have a

```
public abstract class Super{

    protected static int BASE = 1;

    public int foo(){
        //do some computation with BASE, e.g:
        return BASE + 1;
    }
}
```

and a couple static classes inheriting from it:

```
public static abstract class Sub extends Super{
    //this class should keep BASE at 1
}

static class SubSub1 extends Sub{
    //this class should change BASE to 0
    static{
        SubSub1.BASE = 0;
    }
}

static class SubSub2 extends Sub{
    //this class should in effect have a BASE of 1
}
```

And yes, this fails.

The problem obviously is that since SubSub1 is a static class, if it is to change BASE, Super.BASE must be static.

But if Super.BASE is static, then SubSub1.Base IS Super.BASE.

How do I best achieve what I'm trying to do? (No, I can't make the classes non-static, and assume there are a lot of subclasses.)

I'd appreciate the help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why are you doing this?

Comment: I don't think static classes are what you think they are. Any outer class is static, be default. Static only applies to nested classes, which contain a reference to the outer class, unless static.

Comment: A static class doesn't mean all its variables need to be static. Make `BASE` be non-static. (Also, all-caps variable names implies a constant by default, which this isn't -- you should name the variable `base`). Alternatively, you could make an `abstract protected int getBase()` method in the base class, and then have subclasses implement it.

Comment: There is only one BASE. All the subclasses have access to that same static field.

Comment: Remember that "static" infers "single instance". By definition, if you want your variable "BASE" to have different values according to its context, it means that it's not static. Just declare it as a non-static variable, and you should achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. Unfortunately, I cannot change BASE from SubSub1 if I don't make it static - which IS part of the issue.

Comment: Sure you can, just not in the `static {...}` block.

Answer (score 0):

There are no static classes in Java. All Java classes are implicitly static, except nested classes. Interfaces, Annotations and Enums are always static.

The actual issue is a different one: there is no static inheritance in Java. A subclass does not get a copy of the static superclass field, it gets the same field. Whether you reference it as SubSub.BASE or as Super.BASE doesn't matter, it is Super.BASE

Comment: "There are no static classes in Java. All classes are implicitly static" <-- these two statements contradict each other

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the "abstract protected int getBase()" wasn't so bad an idea - I just didn't like that "abstract" part since I would have had to implement that in all non-abstract subclasses.

This, on the other hand, seems to be working and allows me to change BASE only where I need it to change:

```
public abstract class Super{

    protected int BASE = 1;

    protected void setBase(){}

    public int foo(){
        setBase();
        return BASE + 1;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public static abstract class Sub extends Super{
    //this class should keep BASE at 1
}

static class SubSub1 extends Sub{
    //this class should change BASE to 0
    @Override
    protected void setBase(){
        BASE = 0;
    }
}

static class SubSub2 extends Sub{
    //this class should still have a BASE of 1
}
```

Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: You don't need the `setBase()` method. You can simply put the `BASE = 0;` assignment into an instance initializer block or constructor.

Comment: Some subclasses have too many constructors. But idiot that I am, I forgot initializer blocks can be non-static. Thank you.